# Is it possible to directly import a macro in Julia?

Tags: import, macros, namespaces, julia

I would like to load a single macro from a package without including all of the other parts of the package. Just like how a specific function can be imported, like:

```
using Package1: function1
```

The reason why I would like this, is not only to load solely the desired part of the package, but also to show explicitly where the macro is loaded from.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Any top-level variable in a module or package can be imported.

```
julia> module A
           x = 1
           
           macro foo(ex)
               ex
           end
       end
Main.A

julia> using .A: x, @foo

julia> x
1

julia> @foo 2 + 2
4
```

However, note that `using` and `import` statements still load the entire package. The part that you have control over is which names get added to your namespace.

Comment: Thank you! Luckily it is done how you would expect it to be, good to know. Because of your answer I was able to tackle the real problem which turned out to be the dependence of the macro on a function inside the package, which I did not load (add to the namespace).